# Automatically open a file when a solution/project loads

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

Is it possible to open a file when a file when a Visual Studio project or solution loads?

I'v got vague recollections of downloading some source code, unzipping, opening the solution and the readme opened automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the readme file open when you close Visual Studio. It will reopen it the next time you open the solution.

I think the open files are stored in the Project.csproj.user file. So as long as you don't delete that, it won't forget.

Comment: This was some source code I downloaded and didn't have the .user file. I'm pretty sure I opened the project or solution file and saw a tag of some description like `<openOnLoad>`. Either that or I'm hallucinating.

Comment: That would be a cool feature, I hope someone can help you find out how it works!

Comment: I know this is possible because I saw it happened when I open a project for first time. I still looking on how to do it.

Comment: This occurs with Project_Readme.html the first time a ASP.Net Core Web Application is opened. I'm not sure about what magic makes that happen.