# Automatically open a file, when project is imported into IDE

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, ide

**Problem**: I am trying to force IDEA/Eclipse to open a README.md file, once project is imported into workspace. After searching for a bit already, I can't find a solution. So my **question**:

> Is there a way to force IDE to open a file automatically?

---

- I know that there are plugins for viewing mark-up files, but this is not what I am looking for
- Question is the same as this one : [Automatically open a file when a solution/project loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894039/automatically-open-a-file-when-a-solution-project-loads), but I want a **new** project to be opened with a file.

Comment: How do you "open" the project? Are there already IntelliJ project files? 
Open the `readme.md` file directly isn't not an option?

Comment: I am importing the project via maven (but don't think it's relevant here). Nope, not an option, unfortunately. Doing A/B testing so would like to force the file to be opened by default automatically.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ Idea provides a CLI. When you try to open a `pom.xml` and there are no IntelliJ Idea project files, the project will be imported. Else the project will be opened.

I assume from your comments, that you import new projects on a regular base. So, open the `pom.xml`, wait a few seconds to give IntelliJ the chance to create project files and then open the `README.md` will open that file in your fresh imported project.

The following bash script worked for me:

```
idea pom.xml & sleep 5 && idea README.md
```

Don't know if that is an option, because I don't your way to work. Do you like command lines or not aso.

Read [How to import a Maven project with Intellij Command line tool with command "idea pom.xml"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249527/how-to-import-a-maven-project-with-intellij-command-line-tool-with-command-idea) in order to get CLI working.

Comment: I upvote your answer, because I find it useful. But,unfortunately,  it doesn't answer my question :) I would like to get some config set once and for all projects. The script would require to be run every time. Anyway, thanks a lot! :)